# Pyglet 2.0: How to Manipulate light in 3D projection?

Tags: python, opengl, 3d, pyglet, lighting

For those familiar with 3D games in Pyglet version 2.0, can you help me out with a lighting issue and maybe clarify how pyglet's new graphics classes work?

I am basically attempting to simulate a day/night cycle for my 3D world, which, of course, would require me to manipulate the scene's light (pos,color, and brightness). My world is currently lit with some default light source, however, I can't change any of its properties. The only thing I know is that it's fixed to the "camera's" position. Changing the window's view projection changes the angle of the light.

There are already a few questions with solutions pertaining to OpenGL lights in previous pyglet versions. But Pyglet 2.0 seems to work very differently in that none of those solutions work for me. Trying to change the light's properties with Opengl calls like   glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, (GLfloat*4)(1, 0, .5, 0)) doesn't affect this default light. Even when I disable gl_lighting and GL_LIGHT0, my model stays lit. I've scoured pyglet's code to find where the default light is enabled and defined with no success.
Am I doing something wrong or in the wrong order? Or does lighting just work differently in pyglet 2.0?

Below is my code. I only left out the HUD and World classes.

for the App Class:

```
class App(object):
def __init__(self):
    #Initialize Window
    self.world = World(50)
    self.win = Window(1280, 900, self.world)
    self.win.active = True
    self.hud = Hud(self.win,self.world)

def run(self):
    while not self.win.has_exit:
        self.win.dispatch_events()

        self.win.clear()
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        
        
        self.win.camera.ProjectWorld()
        self.world.Draw()

        self.win.camera.ProjectHud()
        self.hud.Draw()

        self.win.flip()
```

the Camera Class:

```
class Camera(object):
def __init__(self, win):
    self.win = win
    self.ZOOM_IN_FACTOR = 1.05
    self.ZOOM_OUT_FACTOR = 1/self.ZOOM_IN_FACTOR

    #initialize camera values
    self.zoom_level = 1
    self.modelposx = 0
    self.modelposy = 0


def ProjectWorld(self):
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    self.win.projection = self.win.modelview
    self.win.view = Mat4.from_translation(Vec3(-self.modelposx,-self.modelposy,-100*self.zoom_level))
    

def ProjectHud(self):
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    self.win.projection = self.win.uiview
    self.win.view = Mat4.from_translation(Vec3(0, 0, -50*self.zoom_level))
```

and Window Class:

```
class Window(window.Window):
def __init__(self, width, height, world):
    #Initialize Window
    conf = Config(sample_buffers=1, samples=4, depth_size=16, double_buffer=True)
    super(Window,self).__init__(width, height, caption='World Generator', config=conf, resizable=True)        
    self.camera = Camera(self)
    self.modelview = Mat4.perspective_projection(0,width,0,height, z_near=0.01, z_far = 400, fov=60)
    self.uiview = Mat4.orthogonal_projection(0, width, 0, height, z_near = 0.01, z_far = 400)

    
def init_gl(self, width, height):

    # Set 3D 
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)

    
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, (GLfloat*4)(.5,.5,1,1))
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, (GLfloat*4)(1,1,1,1))
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, (GLfloat*4)(1, 0, .5, 0))
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)

    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE)

    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    
    # Set clear color
    pyglet.gl.glClearColor(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0)        

    # Set viewport
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)


def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
    # Move camera
    self.camera.modelposx -= (dx*self.camera.zoom_level)/10
    self.camera.modelposy -= (dy*self.camera.zoom_level)/10
    print(dy*self.camera.modelposx)
    print(dx*self.camera.modelposy)

def on_resize(self, width, height):
    self.init_gl(width, height)
    self.projection = self.uiview
    self.view = self.view.translate(Vec3(-50,-50,-50))  

def on_mouse_scroll(self, x, y, dx, dy):
    # Get scale factor
    f = self.camera.ZOOM_IN_FACTOR if dy > 0 else self.camera.ZOOM_OUT_FACTOR if dy < 0 else 1
    # If zoom_level is in the proper range
    if .2 < self.camera.zoom_level*f < 5:
        self.camera.zoom_level *= f
```

Please let me know if I should include anything else in this post!

Comment: Your problem isn't about Pyglet, it's about the legacy OpenGL fixed-function light model. PyGlet just provides the OpenGL instructions. The instructions are implemented by the graphics driver and specified in the [OpenGL 2.0 API Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec20.pdf).

Comment: See [pyglet](https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet): *"NOTE! The pyglet-1.5-maintenance branch is the current stable release. The master branch contains the the development code for the upcoming 2.0 release, and may be unstable."*. If pyglet changes the engine under the hood, your approach using the deprecated light model  may not work at all. Likely you have to write a shader program.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you for your response. I also see this mentioned on Pyglet's github: "Please note that pyglet v1.5 will likely be the last version to support legacy OpenGL. Future releases of pyglet will be targeting OpenGL 3.3+." I assume there is a different/new light model that I learn how to implement? And that is what you mean by writing a shader program?

Comment: In OpenGL 3.3+ there is no light model. You need to implement your own light model in a shader program. e.g.: https://rabbid76.github.io/graphics-snippets/html/tools/light_model_view.html

Comment: @Rabbid76 Gotcha. I will look further into that. thanks again